# Avalon dock DocumentTitleTemplate vs DocumentHeaderDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, avalondock

Can you please explain the difference between `DocumentHeaderDataTemplate` and `DocumentTitleTemplate` in avalonDock.

They are properties of DockingManger, but I want to be sure how to use them.

```
<xcad:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding OpenViewers}"
                     x:Name="MainTabControl"
                     LayoutItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageSelectionTemplate}"
                     ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveTabItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     DocumentHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentHeaderDataTemplate}"
                     DocumentTitleTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentTitleDataTemplate}" 
                     IsHitTestVisible="True" 
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentTitleTemplate` is use in the `Template` of `FloatingDocumentWindow`.
`DocumentHeaderTemplate` is used in the `Template` of `LayoutDocumentTabItem`.

Comment: ok Thanks one template is when the tab is floating as a window  and the other is when it is docked. got it